OutOfMemory Exception when building Java 8 project IntelliJ, but works fine with Maven
I have a Java 8 project in intellij. When I build the project using Maven (clean compile verify), it works fine. However, when I try to build the project using IntelliJ's "Build Project" feature, I encounter an OutOfMemory Exception.
What could be the cause of this !!!?
I tried to increase the memory for Intelij and also maven but it didn't change anything

Just use clean verify (if the clean is really required) instead clean compile verify.... that duplicates some parts check https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle

Try the following three steps:

Check for Classpath Conflicts and Clean IntelliJ Cache
Switch to Maven Build in IntelliJ
Increase IDE PermGen Space

PS: Also try deleting the build file, sometimes that's all you need to do :)

Thank you very much for the hint about the build file!!! It helped me realize that I had made a mistake in my pom.xml. I had accidentally added the swagger-maven-plugin twice—one was properly configured, but the other was not. This led to the issue I was experiencing.
I had initially overlooked this part of the build setup, and it turns out the problem was unrelated to Jersey or IntelliJ.
